# Custom Gem in /vendor/gems not Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rails-engines

I recently decided to take some functionality that I have in several of my Rails apps and extract it into an Engine. I have now finished the Engine and I'm trying to install the finished gem into one of my apps.

This particular gem isn't something that I want to be public, so I packaged the gem with `gem build my_gem.gemspec` and then put the packaged gem in the vendor/gems folder of my application. Then, I added `gem 'my_gem', '0.0.1', :path => 'vendor/gems'` to my gemfile and ran `bundle install`.

Unfortunately though, Rails doesn't seem to be loading the gem and I can't seem to require it manually:

```
$ bundle exec rails console --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 3.2.11)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
irb(main):001:0> MyGem
NameError: uninitialized constant MyGem
        from (irb):1
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> require 'my_gem'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- my_gem
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from (irb):2
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I fix this?

---

**Edit:** Here's my gem environment information.

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.16
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - c:/Users/Ajedi32/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `gem env` to check where Ruby is searching for gems.

You then want to append the directory you put your gem in, to the GEM_PATH environment variable. e.g.:

```
  export GEM_PATH="./vendor/gems:$GEM_PATH"
```

See also:  http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/12

If you are using a Gemfile, you can also do this:

```
  gem 'my-gem', '0.0.1', :path => 'vendor/gems/my-gem'
```

(you have to add the name of your gem directory to the path)

Comment: "gem directory" implies that I'm using an unpackaged gem though, right? Is that how I'm supposed to do it? Because the way things currently are (I'm using a packaged gem), `:path => 'vendor/gems/my_gem'` gives the error `The path 'C:/Users/Ajedi32/my_app/vendor/gems/my_gem' does not exist.`

Comment: you will need a `my-gem.gemspec` file in that directory. You could also put that directory somewhere under Git version control, and then point the path to the URL which can check out the directory

Comment: Ah okay, so I can't use a bundled version of the gem? I.E. `my_gem.gem`? Or is that what the `GEM_PATH` variable is for?

Comment: I have not tried it with a bundled gem. It definitely works without bundling it. Putting it on an internally accessible server where you have a user-account which is accessible via SSH is enough to host your own Git repository. You could also use a private GitHub repo.

Comment: Okay, I tried it unpackaged and everything worked fine. Thanks for your help. As for using a private git repo, that's a really interesting idea. I already use BitBucket, so it probably wouldn't be that hard to set up... I'll look into it.

Comment: you could also use a private could-server. Here's a howto: http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux . These are some providers with low cost plans: [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com)   , [Linode](http://www.linode.com/)